# Insert certain tag attributes in user input in php

Tags: php, html, anchor

I am taking post as input from user. User can input `<a href=""></a>` tag in the post. What I need to do is, if any user input any `<a>` tag then I have to insert a class like `<a class="user" href=""></a>` and save to database.

How can I do this easy way? I am using `strip_tags()` to remove all tags except `<a>` in user input.

Comment: can't you work with javascript? It would be much much easier to grab the submit, add what you need to add and the send it to php or wherever you need to send it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that using a regex, but it's hard to find a good one that **always** works. [See this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags).

What you can use, is [HTMLPurifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/). I use it to cleanup all posted information. You can select which tag to keep, wich attribute to keep for each tag, etc ..

> HTML filter that guards against XSS and ensures standards-compliant output.

One thing you can do with HTMLPurifier, is extend the core code and then, for a given tag, extends the class to add a class for each entity.

You can check [this (quick) example](http://htmlpurifier.org/phorum/read.php?3,6541,6552) where user wants to convert this:

```
<p>This is a paragraph</p>
<p>Another one</p>
```

Into this:

```
<p class="myclass">This is a paragraph</p>
<p class="myclass">Another one</p>
```

**Edit:**

Here is a quick and dirty example that you can test on your own:

```
<?php

require_once 'lib/library/HTMLPurifier.auto.php';

class HTMLPurifier_AttrTransform_AnchorClass extends HTMLPurifier_AttrTransform
{
    public function transform($attr, $config, $context)
    {
      // keep predefined class
      if (isset($attr['class']))
      {
        $attr['class'] .= ' myclass';
      }
      else
      {
        $attr['class'] = 'myclass';
      }

      return $attr;
    }
}

$dirty_html = '<p><a href=""></a>
<a target="_blank" href=""></a>
<a href="" class="toto"></a>
<a href="" style="oops"></a></p>';

$options = array(
  'HTML' => array(
    'Allowed' => 'a[href|target|class]')
);
$config     = HTMLPurifier_Config::create($options);
$htmlDef    = $config->getHTMLDefinition(true);

$anchor     = $htmlDef->addBlankElement('a');
$anchor->attr_transform_post[] = new HTMLPurifier_AttrTransform_AnchorClass();

$purifier   = new HTMLPurifier($config);

$clean_html = $purifier->purify($dirty_html);

var_dump($clean_html);
```

It outputs:

```
string '<a href="" class="myclass"></a>

<a href="" class="myclass"></a>

<a href="" class="toto myclass"></a>

<a href="" class="myclass"></a>' (length=135)
```

I use a custom configuration to keep some attributes in `<a>` tag, that's why it removes `style` but not `target`. You can check the [documentation](http://htmlpurifier.org/live/configdoc/plain.html) about that.

Comment: Thanks for your link. It is just perfect answer. But I still can not figure it out exactly. Could you give me the code how exactly i should write it in this case? I am not using object oriented PHP. So im little confused with the example.

Comment: need another help. How can i delete all the tags except <a> tags from the post. In your given code, if i include <p> or other safe tags it shows but i want to remove them. Only <a> tag should be present in the post.